# Data flow reading date column as null

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a csv file and I am reading it using SFTP/CSV dataset in the data flow source. In the dataset setting I am able to preview the data.
I have a date column in the format of mm/dd/yyyy and I have to populate this date column in a different column of database. but while reading the data and checking in data preview, every time this date column is coming as null.

I have to read the date column and populate in a database column but still data flow is not able to read the data form csv file.
can someone help me to understand where could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the Input CSV data is as below:
[image]

StudentID   Total  Marks    DOE
1       100        4/23/2021
2   200 4/24/2021
3   300 4/25/2021
4   400 4/26/2021
5   500 4/27/2021
6   600 4/28/2021
7   700 4/29/2021
8   800 4/30/2021
9   900 5/1/2021

At Source settings, in Projection Tab, Import Projection and Set Type of the Date Column as "string":
[image]

Go to Source Data Preview to see mm/dd/yyyy:
[image]

Sink level Data Preview with mm/dd/yyyy:
[image]

Also after running Pipeline, in Azure SQL Database, the result shows in expected Date Format:

[image]

Comment: In my case, the CSV file date column is date type only so when I am importing the projection in source of data flow it is taking it as Date data type and in data preview it is showing as NULL. So I tried changing the data type in projection from Date to String and converted it with toDate function in derived column as toDate(date_Column,mm/dd/yyyy). Now in SQl data base I can see the data in this formate--> yyyy-dd-mm.  I am still not sure why it is giving me null in data preview of source stage.

Comment: If you have changed at Source Projection the Data Type from Date to String, then do not use Derived Column with toDate function. Simply run the pipeline or check Data Preview, it would be displayed.

Comment: That will throw an error because my target column is date type and it is showing as data mismatch